# cannot connect sftp to ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, sftp

Hi can anyone help me figure out why I cannot connect to my server via Filezilla.

It was working not long ago and I have not changed any settings.

everytime i try to connect to the server i get `Server unexpectedly closed the network connection`

I have turned my ufw firewall off, and also checked in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make sure the port is set correctly.

I am able to connect to the server by putty using the same port.

Can anyone point out anything I may have missed or solutions that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this now.

i looked in `/etc/hosts.deny` and noticed that the ip addresses of the machines i used to connect were in there.

So i have placed them in `/etc/hosts.allow` so hopefully this wont happen again.